# clojure when macro

Tags: clojure

I was browsing the clojure source and I was surprised by the way the when macro is defined:

```
user=> (source when)
(defmacro when
  "Evaluates test. If logical true, evaluates body in an implicit do."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [test & body]
  (list 'if test (cons 'do body)))
nil
user=>
```

I was expecting it to be written something like this instead:

```
(defmacro when [test & body] `(if ~test (do ~@body)))
```

Why was the actual macro written in this less usual way?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

core.clj is built from top to bottom, starting with just what Java provides and building up all the requirements for Clojure as it goes. When `when` is defined the syntax quote does not yet exist.
The `when` macro is defined on [line 456](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/3bd1bb3c8d01f268eb780e87f4f5d1af911734e5/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L456) of core.clj and the requirements for syntax-quote are not available until [line 682.](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/3bd1bb3c8d01f268eb780e87f4f5d1af911734e5/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L682) **the when macro is used to define syntax quoting**

Comment: Line 680 appears to be the defmulti macro. And syntax quote (I assume) is a reader macro. Can you elaborate on exactly what function/macro is required for syntax quote?

Comment: Kevin, why don't you just follow the links behind those line numbers. There is no `defmulti` at or near line 682 so you're probably looking at some other version of this file. As to what is required for syntax quote, it's simple: **everything defined above line 682** in this particular version of the file.

Comment: @marco topolnok: I did follow your link. Just realized the line numbers get screwed up on the iPhone. Thanks.